# User comment showing number instead of username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've been trying to figure this out awhile now and just cannot get it to work properly. I'm using devise and I'm trying to show the username of a user that commented on an object called "pit" which is basically the same thing as a blog post but with some more features.  Initially I found that it wasn't saving the user id in my comments model but I fixed that and now it just renders the above. All searches here have yielded some help but no complete solution. Any and all help  plus criticisms is welcome. Thanks.

The page is rendering this below instead of a name

```
"<User: 0x00000105929950>"
```

I have a partial called _comment.html.erb in which the code is supposed to render below

```
<p>

  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
  <%= comment.user %>

</p>

  <p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.pit, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

Comments Controller :

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


 def create
  @pit= Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.build(comments_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save

  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

def destroy
    @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
    @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
  end

def show
end

  private

def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id)
end
```

end

Pits controller

```
def index
  @pit = Pit.all
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pit = @user.pits
  @pits = Pit.order('created_at DESC')
end

def create
  @user = current_user
  @pit = current_user.pits.create(pit_params)
    if @pit.save
      redirect_to @pit
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def show
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
end

def update
end


private

def pit_params
    params.require(:pit).permit(:topic, :summary, :image, :video_url, :author, :user_id)
end
```

end

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @users = User.all
    authorize User
  end


   def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end




  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pits
  has_many :comments
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  def name
    name = first_name + ' ' + last_name
  end



  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,




 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Pit Model

```
class Pit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment Model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pit
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: that is user object. you need to display a specific attribute, like user.name

Comment: Can you try `<%= comment.user.username %>` or `<%= comment.user.name %>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write

```
comment.user.name
```

instead of

```
comment.user
```

Comment: Could of sworn I tried that pixelearth but it worked. I must have tried that prior to fixing the model. Thanks a lot!

Comment: just remember that user is an association (an object instance), not really a printable value. you're seeing that output because :to_s is called (I think, inherited from somewhere up the inheritance chain).

Comment: Good to know. Im still a newbie here so I'm really trying to figure what is going on here while I build this thing. Thanks for the info.